# How to conditionally iterate through a mapping of structs and only return some structs - Solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm learning solidity by writing a contract to store and retrieve patient medical records. Does anyone know why the functions "getRecordByAddressMap" and "getRecordByAddressStruct" don't work? They compile, but the transactions revert.

The logic is quite simple, the functions iterate through the mapping (or array in the other case), checks if the addresses match, adds the structs to an array, then returns that array.

What am I missing here?

```
contract PatientRecords{
  uint256 public recordID = 1;
  mapping (uint256 => mapping (address => Records)) records;

  struct Records {
      address patient;
      address hospital;
      uint256 admissionDate;
      uint256 dischargeDate;
      uint256 visitReason;
  }

  Records[] recordsarray;
  Records[] getstructs;

  constructor() {
      addRecord(0x3719dB98b075Ff10886Fc29431Ffc2006fFF0005, 
        0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 20220320, 20220330, 1);
      addRecord(0x3719dB98b075Ff10886Fc29431Ffc2006fFF0005, 
        0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 20220333, 20220333, 2);
      addRecord(0x60814DB6b62fE178d7F91239078e3c20fB857E04, 
        0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 20220310, 20220311, 3);
  }

// Add a record to the mapping
  function addRecord (
    address _patientAddress,
    address _hospital,
    uint256 _admissionDate,
    uint256 _dischargeDate,
    uint256 _visitReason)
    public
  {
      records[recordID][_patientAddress].patient = _patientAddress;
      records[recordID][_patientAddress].hospital = _hospital;
      records[recordID][_patientAddress].admissionDate = _admissionDate;
      records[recordID][_patientAddress].dischargeDate = _dischargeDate;
      records[recordID][_patientAddress].visitReason = _visitReason;

      recordsarray.push(Records(_patientAddress, _hospital, _admissionDate, _dischargeDate, _visitReason));
      recordID++;
  }

// Retrieve a record by the patient address and record ID (count)
  function getRecordByID(address _patientAddress, uint256 _recordID) public view returns(Records memory) {
    return records[_recordID][_patientAddress];
  }

// Retrieve a record by the patient address (Mapping method)
  function getRecordByAddressMap(address _patientAddress) public view returns (Records[] memory){
    Records[] memory rec = new Records[](recordID);
      for (uint i = 1; i < recordID; i++) {
        if (_patientAddress == records[i][_patientAddress].patient == true) {
          rec[i] = records[i][_patientAddress];
          } else {
            continue;
          }
      }
    return rec;
  }

    // Retrieve a record by the patient address (Struct method)
  function getRecordByAddressStruct(address _patientAddress) public returns(Records[] memory) {
    Records[] storage _getstructs = getstructs;
    for (uint i = 1; i < recordID; i++) {
      if (_patientAddress == recordsarray[i].patient == true) {
        Records memory newRecord = Records({
          patient: recordsarray[i].patient,
          hospital: recordsarray[i].hospital,
          admissionDate: recordsarray[i].admissionDate,
          dischargeDate: recordsarray[i].dischargeDate,
          visitReason: recordsarray[i].visitReason
        });
        _getstructs.push(newRecord);
        } else {
          continue;
        }
    }
    return _getstructs;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate with `for` keyword, you don't use record Id try to use [array].lenght.
In your case, in `getRecordByAddressMap` function change it in this way:

```
// Retrieve a record by the patient address (Mapping method)
  function getRecordByAddressMap(address _patientAddress) public view returns (Records[] memory){
    Records[] memory rec = new Records[](recordID);
      for (uint i = 1; i <= rec.length; i++) {
        if (_patientAddress == records[i][_patientAddress].patient == true) {
          rec[i] = records[i][_patientAddress];
          } else {
            continue;
          }
      }
    return rec;
  }
```

And in `getRecordByAddressStruct` function change it with this:

```
  // Retrieve a record by the patient address (Struct method)
  function getRecordByAddressStruct(address _patientAddress) public returns(Records[] memory) {
    Records[] storage _getstructs = getstructs;
    for (uint i = 1; i < _getstructs.length; i++) {
      if (_patientAddress == recordsarray[i].patient == true) {
        Records memory newRecord = Records({
          patient: recordsarray[i].patient,
          hospital: recordsarray[i].hospital,
          admissionDate: recordsarray[i].admissionDate,
          dischargeDate: recordsarray[i].dischargeDate,
          visitReason: recordsarray[i].visitReason
        });
        _getstructs.push(newRecord);
        } else {
          continue;
        }
    }
    return _getstructs;
  }
```

Comment: Epic, it works now. Quite peculiar that you need to iterate on the [array].lenght. Anyway, thanks a bunch!!